# Can you do an SQL INNER JOIN statement that has more than one INNER JOIN condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have an SQL query in which I need there to be more than one condition in which a record from one table is joined in the results.

Specifically, I need to have a record included if it has a foreign key value that is the same as the id an entry in another table - and ALSO if the foreign key value is NULL.

So, this is what I have now...

```
SELECT
table1.value1,
table1.value2,
table2.value1

FROM
dbo.table1 table1
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 table2
ON table1.table2_id = table2.id
WHERE table1.value1 = 'blah'
```

Which works fine.  HOWEVER, I ALSO need to return all of the values from table1 in which table1.table2_id is NULL.

So far I've tried this...

```
SELECT
table1.value1,
table1.value2,
table2.value1

FROM
dbo.table1 table1
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 table2
ON table1.table2_id = table2.id OR table1.table2_id is NULL
WHERE table1.value1 = 'blah'
```

And it just sends the query into an infinite loop.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can join for multiple condition. Can you show us some sample data and desire result? JOIN when table2_id is NULL doesnt make much sense. Is like you said, I will drink all coke with expire date today and all empty bottles.

Comment: You want a LEFT OUTER JOIN, not an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Simply replace INNER JOIN with LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a separate condition in the `JOIN` clause, but your scenario doesn't really work for that. Your condition says that if table1.table2_id is NULL, then *all* rows from table2 match it - that's not quite an infinite loop, but would probably be fairly large.

Probably easiest to use a `LEFT JOIN` to return all rows from `table1`, then a `WHERE` clause to filter down to ones that matched or that are null:

```
SELECT
   table1.value1,
   table1.value2,
   table2.value1
FROM table1 table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table2 table2 ON
   table1.table2_id = table2.id
WHERE 
   table1.value1 = 'blah'
   AND (table2.id IS NOT NULL OR table1.table2_id IS NULL)
```

You could also use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT
   table1.value1,
   table1.value2,
   table2.value1
FROM table1 table1
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 table2 ON
   table1.table2_id = table2.id
WHERE 
   table1.value1 = 'blah'
UNION ALL
SELECT
   table1.value1,
   table1.value2,
   NULL
FROM table1 table1
WHERE 
   table1.value1 = 'blah'
   AND table1.table2_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Ack, I think the union is just likely to be confusing at this point...  Very complete answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT JOIN to get all the records from table 1, and it will return a NULL for any value that it cannot match with in table 2.

```
SELECT
table1.value1,
table1.value2,
table2.value1

FROM
dbo.table1 table1
LEFT JOIN dbo.table2 table2
ON table1.table2_id = table2.id
WHERE table1.value1 = 'blah'
```